# .opendistro-alerting-* - ALLOCATION_FAILED - UNASSIGNED

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am running OpenSearch 1.2 R20220323-P4 on AWS and my cluster is in a yellow status. After some investigating, I found the following indices in an UNASSIGNED state with a reason of ALLOCATION_FAILED.

```
index                                                                         shard prirep state      node                             unassigned.reason
.opendistro-alerting-config                                                   1     r      UNASSIGNED                                  ALLOCATION_FAILED
.opendistro-alerting-alerts                                                   0     r      UNASSIGNED                                  ALLOCATION_FAILED
```

We had some alerting set up but it was removed and there are no entries in Alerting-* Alerts, Monitors or Destinations.

I have tried deleting these indices but I get the following error message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "no permissions for [] and User [name=test-user, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "no permissions for [] and User [name=test-user, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=]"
  },
  "status" : 403
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?